# How to make my kill switch more effective?

Tags: python, while-loop

I made an auto clicker with a kill switch. Once you press "s" the program stops. The only problem is that you have to hold the "s" key until the Auto_Click function finishes. In the code, I set the function to run for 0.5 seconds.

How would I make my kill switch more effective? I want the program to stop the moment you hit the key.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pyautogui
import time 
import keyboard

# The Switch
on_off = True 

print("Auto Clicker Started")

# This function does the clicking
def Auto_Click():
    width, height = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.click(width, height)
    time.sleep(0.5)

# Checks if you hit the kill button. If you did not hit the kill button, run the Auto_Click function. 
while on_off == True:

  if keyboard.is_pressed('s') == True:
        on_off = False
        print("Auto Clicker Killed")
        
  Auto_Click()
```

Comment: If you sleep for 0.5s, it doesn’t seem very surprising that it will take >0.5s for your program to respond to a keypress. Sleep for a shorter time.

Comment: If I don't use a pause, the mouse will click faster. I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using threading. By creating a separate thread to check for "s" keypress, it can run alongside the auto clicker. This means there is no delay when the key is pressed.

```
# This function does the clicking
def Auto_Click():
    width, height = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.click(width, height)
    time.sleep(0.5)

def check_press():
    global on_off
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s') == True:
        on_off = False
        print("Auto Clicker Killed")
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1) #Check every 10th of a second
        check_press()

check_thread = threading.Thread(target = check_press)
check_thread.start()

# Checks if you hit the kill button. If you did not hit the kill button, run the Auto_Click function. 
while on_off == True:
  Auto_Click()
```

**Edit** - Add a resume button

```
def check_press():
    global on_off
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s') and on_off:
        on_off = False
        print("Auto Clicker Killed")
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('r') and not on_off:
        on_off = True
        print("Auto Clicker Restarted")
    time.sleep(0.1) #Check every 10th of a second
    check_press()

check_thread = threading.Thread(target = check_press)
check_thread.start()

# Checks if you hit the kill button. If you did not hit the kill button, run the Auto_Click function. 
while True:
    while on_off == True:
      Auto_Click()
```

I've bound the "r" key to resume and changed how the program works to allow this to happen. Now there is an infinite loop trying to start the autoclicker so the program does not stop when the clicker is stopped. Then inside `check_press` the value of `on_off` is set depending on what keys have been pressed. The infinite loop running in the other thread will start the autoclicker loop when `on_off` is set to True.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked! Do you also think you could real quick make a resume button?

Comment: I've edited the question to do that.